# Profile image is not updating even after selecting a new image from gallery or camera

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

Hello everyone and thanks in advance to everyone who helps me :)

I want to let people choose a picture from the gallery (like a profile picture)

and the selected image will remain even after exiting the app ...
And when I go back into the app I want see picture I chose
How can I do this please?

USE-Swift 4

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

        @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

            imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
        }

        func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
            dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

            let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
            imageView.image = image
            imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill

            dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

            let controller = UIImagePickerController()
            controller.delegate = self
            controller.sourceType = .photoLibrary
            present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

Comment: what do you want please specify

Comment: just save your picture in local db until user update it.

Comment: Just select an image from the gallery or take a picture ... and the selected image will remain even after exiting the app ...
And when I go back into the app I want see picture I chose

Answer (score 1):

You can use `saveImage()` method to save image in document directory when you pick any image. An call `getImage()` method to get image in viewDidLoad and set it on imageView.

```
func saveImage(_ image: UIImage) {
    let url = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first?.appendingPathComponent("Profile.jpg")

    let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.8)
    try? imageData?.write(to: url!)
}

func getImage() -> UIImage? {
    let url = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first?.appendingPathComponent("Profile.jpg")

    if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!) {
        return UIImage(data: data)
    }
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use user default and check user default value in ViewDidLoad method

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

                @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

                override func viewDidLoad() {
                    super.viewDidLoad()
                    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
                     let possibleOldImagePath = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "path") as! String?
            if let oldImagePath = possibleOldImagePath {
                let oldFullPath = self.documentsPathForFileName(oldImagePath)
                let oldImageData = NSData(contentsOfFile: oldFullPath)
                // here is your saved image:
                imageView = UIImage(data: oldImageData)
            }
                    imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
                }

                func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
                    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
                func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

                    let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
                    imageView.image = image
                    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill

    // save to userDefaults

            let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1)
            let relativePath = "image_\(NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate).jpg"
            let path = self.documentsPathForFileName(relativePath)
            imageData.writeToFile(path, atomically: true)
            UserDefaults.standard.set(relativePath, forKey: "path")
            UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

                    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                }

                override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

                    let controller = UIImagePickerController()
                    controller.delegate = self
                    controller.sourceType = .photoLibrary
                    present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            }
```

Method for path

```
 func documentsPathForFileName(name: String) -> String {
            let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true);
            let path = paths[0] as String;
            let fullPath = path.stringByAppendingPathComponent(name)

            return fullPath
        }
```